# Microsoft SQL Server 2012, export to sql syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am playing with Microsoft SQL Server 2012, creating tables in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Is there any way to export those created tables to sql syntax so I get some .sql file with code like `CREATE TABLE...` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio in the Object Explorer you can right click on the table you want to export and select Script Table as > CREATE To > File ...

For the entire database you can right click on the database and select Tasks > Generate Scripts... and then use the wizard to generate the scripts for the database objects you wish to script.

Answer (score 2):

You have your answer here in [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245282.aspx) but, long story short, in the management studio you have the option to generate scripts (right button over a database in the explorer tree)

Comment: guess what, i prefer stackoverflow then technet ;)